# jQuery validate plugin - showErrors option - errorContainer not un-hiding / showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been trying to get a nice validation solution to work for my site, but I'm having trouble with the different options. I have read the docs thoroughly and looked at examples, but I'm still having issues.

My form is in a table. I want each row to have it's own error row beneath it, which would ordinarily be hidden, but which would show for each row as appropriate.

The following options hid and showed the error rows fine, but the error message shown in each error row was the whole concatenation of every error message:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: "required",
        lastName: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: "Enter your first name.",
        lastName: "Enter your last name."
    },
    errorContainer: '.errorRow',
    errorLabelContainer: '.errorRow.appValueColumn',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    }
});
```

so I tried to use the showErrors option as follows:

```
  $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: "Enter your first name.",
            lastName: "Enter your last name."
        },
        errorContainer: '.errorRow',
        errorContainer: '.errorRow.appValueColumn',
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
       $('#'+key).parent().next().children('.appValueColumn').html(errorMap[key]);
});
```

Well, now the errors are all separated and shown in the correct place, but I can't get the `.errorRows` to show. What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source of the validation plugin for the showErrors method, you have:

```
this.settings.showErrors
            ? this.settings.showErrors.call( this, this.errorMap, this.errorList )
            : this.defaultShowErrors();
```

This means that if you provide a custom handler for this method, the default behavior is not executed.

You could either call this.defaultShowErrors() at the end of your own showErrors handler, which will become:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
        $('#'+key).parent().next().children('.appValueColumn')
                  .html(errorMap[key]);
    });
    this.defaultShowErrors();
});
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I followed your code and applied to mine. Error comes onclick submit but at time some page refreshes. Can you please check what mistake i'm making. fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/we7rkrxk/1/

Comment: Well, looking at the console, you can see there is an exception "Uncaught TypeError: this.defaultShowErrors is not a function".
Like I say in the post `this.defaultShowErrors()` should be called at the end of the custom `showErrors` handler, but in the code example, it was enclosed in the `$.each()`!
Good catch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the classname without the leading dot on these lines:

```
errorContainer: 'errorRow',
errorLabelContainer: 'errorRow appValueColumn',
```