# Jquery validate - errorPlacement starting from last input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin. I want to show *one by one* error message at a time onclick of submit.  For that, I haves used the `errorPlacement` callback function to replace message on a target area.

**[Find js Fiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/we7rkrxk/)**

Error message starting from bottom. So last input error message is coming first on click of submit button.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    //onfocusout: true, 
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).parents('#registorForm').find('.form-message').html(error); 
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

    },
});


$("#registorForm").validate({ 
    ignore: [],
    rules: { 
        user_title:{
            required: true,
        }, 
        first_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        middle_name: {
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            required: true
        },
        mobile_number:{
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 12,
            digits: true 
        },
        email_id: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        city: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages:{
        user_title:{
            required:'Your Title is required E.g. Mr., Miss., Ms.'
        },
        first_name:{
            required:'Please Enter Your First Name'
        },
        middle_name:{
            required:'Please Enter Your Middle Name'
        },
        last_name:{
            required:'Please Enter Your Last Name'
        },
        mobile_number:{
            required:'Please Enter Your Mobile Number'
        },
        email_id:{
            required:'Please Enter Your Email id'
        },
        city:{
            required:'Please Enter Your City'
        },

    } 
});
```

[image: Error message starting from bottom. so last input error message is showing on click of submit button.]

**[Find js Fiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/we7rkrxk/)**

Comment: The [tag:formvalidation-plugin] is an entirely different plugin.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some misunderstanding about the callback options.

The `errorPlacement` option is intended for adjusting the placement of *all* individual messages near each input element.  Only the last message is showing because your code is replacing each message with the next message.

You also do not need an empty `invalidHandler` since that option is for firing a custom action when the form is invalid.

If you want to place the messages in another location and control how the messages are displayed within, then you need to look at other options such as [`showErrors`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showErrors), [`errorLabelContainer`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer), and [`errorContainer`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorcontainer).

When using the `showErrors` option, the `errorPlacement` function will *automatically* be suppressed.  In other words, when using the `showErrors` option you will not get messages next to each of the elements.

Within `showErrors`, use the `errorList` argument to pick out the messages and control how you want them to display.  Do not use `this.defaultShowErrors()` as it will effectively restore the functionality of `errorPlacement`.

A crude example of what you can do, but it needs some work...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var summary = "Your form contains " + this.numberOfInvalids() + " errors, see details above.</br>";

        $.each(errorList, function() {
            summary += " * " + this.message + "</br>";
        });

        $(".form-message").html(summary);

        // this.defaultShowErrors(); // default error placement
    }
});
```

DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/p4mw594x/

**More examples of `showErrors`**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788796/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992707/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628801/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23829212/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897507/594235

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer. But is it possible to show error message but input then second and so on onclick of submit?

Comment: @locateganesh, yes, it is possible as evidenced by the code in the additional answers I've linked to.  You simply need to access the appropriate message within the `errorList` object.